# I am getting an error of undefined variable defined within the if statement block

Tags: laravel, if-statement, methods, eloquent

**Hello everyone!Am having an error  below:**

> Undefined variable: c2bTransaction {"userId":12,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined variable: c2bTransaction at BugController.php:140
> I have been trying to figure out what is failing with the below codeAny help will be highly appreciated.

```
public function paysomething(Request $request)
{


    ///$c2bTransaction =[];
    if(Session::has('order_id')) {
        $combined_order = CombinedOrder::find(Session::get('combined_order_id'));

        $request->Msisdn   = (substr($request->Msisdn, 0, 1) == '+') ? str_replace('+', '', $request->Msisdn) : $request->Msisdn;
        $request->Msisdn   = (substr($request->Msisdn, 0, 1) == '0') ? preg_replace('/^0/', '254', $request->Msisdn) : $request->Msisdn;

        $c2bTransaction   = STK::send($request->Msisdn, round($order->grand_total), $request->BillRefNumber);

        if(array_key_exists('errorMessage', $c2bTransaction)) {
            flash($c2bTransaction['errorMessage'])->error();
            return redirect(route('home'));
        }

        // dd($c2bTransaction);

        $combined_order->request    = $c2bTransaction['MerchantRequestID'];
        $combined_order->save();
        //$c2bTransaction = $mpesa->c2b(env('MPESA_SHORT_CODE'), $request->CommandID, $order->grand_total, $request->Msisdn, $request->BillRefNumber);
    } else if(Session::has('payment_type') && Session::get('payment_type') == 'wallet_payment') {
        $request->Msisdn   = (substr($request->Msisdn, 0, 1) == '+') ? str_replace('+', '', $request->Msisdn) : $request->Msisdn;
        $request->Msisdn   = (substr($request->Msisdn, 0, 1) == '0') ? preg_replace('/^0/', '254', $request->Msisdn) : $request->Msisdn;

        $c2bTransaction   = STK::send($request->Msisdn, Session::get('payment_data')['amount'], $request->BillRefNumber);
        //$c2bTransaction = $mpesa->c2b(env('MPESA_SHORT_CODE'), $request->CommandID, Session::get('payment_data')['amount'], $request->Msisdn, $request->BillRefNumber);
    } else if(Session::has('payment_type') && Session::get('payment_type') == 'customer_package_payment') {
        $payment_data = Session::get('payment_data');
        $customer_package_id = $payment_data['customer_package_id'];
        $customer_package_price = CustomerPackage::findOrFail($customer_package_id)->amount;

        $c2bTransaction   = STK::send($request->Msisdn, $customer_package_price, $request->BillRefNumber);
        //$c2bTransaction = $mpesa->c2b(env('MPESA_SHORT_CODE'), $request->CommandID, $customer_package_price, $request->Msisdn, $request->BillRefNumber);
    } else if(Session::has('payment_type') && Session::get('payment_type') == 'seller_package_payment') {
        $payment_data = Session::get('payment_data');
        $seller_package_id = $payment_data['seller_package_id'];
        $seller_package_price = \App\SellerPackage::findOrFail($seller_package_id)->amount;

        $c2bTransaction   = STK::send($request->Msisdn, $seller_package_price, $request->BillRefNumber);
        //$c2bTransaction = $mpesa->c2b(env('MPESA_SHORT_CODE'), $request->CommandID, $seller_package_price, $request->Msisdn, $request->BillRefNumber);

    }
    $payment_type = Session::get('payment_type');

    $payment = $c2bTransaction;

    try{

        if($c2bTransaction['ResponseCode'] != 0){
            // fail or cancel or incomplete
            Session::forget('payment_data');
            flash(translate('Payment incomplete'))->error();
            return redirect()->route('home');

        }
        else {
            if ($payment_type == 'cart_payment') {
                $checkoutController = new CheckoutController;
                return $checkoutController->checkout_done(session()->get('combined_order_id'), json_encode($payment));
            }

            if ($payment_type == 'wallet_payment') {
                $walletController = new WalletController;
                return $walletController->wallet_payment_done(session()->get('payment_data'), json_encode($payment));
            }

            if ($payment_type == 'customer_package_payment') {
                $customer_package_controller = new CustomerPackageController;
                return $customer_package_controller->purchase_payment_done(session()->get('payment_data'), json_encode($payment));
            }
            if($payment_type == 'seller_package_payment') {
                $seller_package_controller = new \App\Http\Controllers\SellerPackageController;
                return $seller_package_controller->purchase_payment_done(session()->get('payment_data'), json_encode($payment));
            }
        }
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
        flash(translate('Payment failed'))->error();
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

}
```

Comment: why is the first line commented out ?

Comment: you need to explain in more detail, and what is your question?

Comment: I was trying to initialize the variable outside the block statement

Answer (score 0):

you should uncomment `$c2bTransaction` staring of if statement

Comment: When I uncomment it  nothing happens.Thats why I have posted it here

Answer (score 0):

We need more details to help you.

But, as we can see in the code that you posted, the variable `c2bTransaction` is undefined because the line were you declare that variable is commented, and probably your method is not accessing your if condition, that's why you should declare the variable before the if statement.

Comment: I think everything in that code is clear unless you are new to programming.I want to access a variable c2bTransaction, the variable is within the if statement block.Forget about the commented code because I have tried it and failed

Comment: So, as you said, "the variable is within the if statement block", if the variable is undefined, your method is not accessing your if statement. Have you ever tried to dump and die your variable inside your if code block?

Comment: I havent tried yet.I can give it a shot then I will post it here